# VS Code comment shortcut in Mac

Tags: html, comments, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to ask if you experience when making comments in HTML languange in VSCode using keyboard shortcut `CMD + /` is giving me `{{/*    */}}` instead of `<!-- -->`. How to resolve this? Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of where you are putting in comments?
VSCs comments will change depending on the tags you are in in an HTML file.
Ex:  // for when in a < script > or < style >

Comment: Im putting the comment here https://snipboard.io/QZOIKF.jpg
and https://snipboard.io/0EcLsI.jpg

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @everyone, the issue has been resolve. I disabled the hugofy extension. Thank you :)